# Why does a Team Site library always has 'Team site' in the folder name when syncing?

Tags: folder, content-and-structure

I'm trying to set up Sharepoint as a Cloud file server, <sub>which is a pain</sub>, but I'm annoyed by the fact that when syncing a library (i.e. root shared folder) the folder structure duplicates the company's name; e.g.:

```
/Sander/Company LTD./Company LTD. Team Site - LibraryName/ActualContent
```

Why can't it just be as simple as

```
/Sander/Company LTD./LibraryName/Actual Content
```

I don't want to mess around with multiple sites, which would create even more clutter. I just want it straight and simple. Too bad I just can't find anything about this on the web..